# Update database on the basis of checked/ unchecked in JTable

Tags: java, swing, checkbox, jtable

I'm in the process of making an attendance application. Right now, I'm working on building the table that will hold the students and allow the user to mark students as absent/present.

The compilable and runnable code below displays my current JTable. It looks how I want it to, but I'm uncertain about how to make the check boxes selectable and also how to gather the check boxes' boolean values. In this table data will come from database table

```
student(std_id,Std_name,total_class,present_class,att_status);
```

I want to show only 3 columns in the table: std_id, std_name, and present/absent(jCheckBox).

How will I change in data base total_class, present_class according to whether or not the jcheckbox is check or unchecked? i means if student are absent then total class will increase +1 and total present class will remain same if student are present than both will +1 .means i have to calculate attendance by total_class(int) and present_class(int) and store them in float att_status. 
 I didn't really understand it. Can someone explain it to me simply?`package my.stdams;

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Vatt1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    static Connection conn;
public Vatt1() {
        initComponents();

        try {

            String userName = "root";
            String password = "aditya";
            String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sams";
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to connect to database.");
        }

    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        entityManager = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("sams?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNullPU").createEntityManager();
        studentQuery = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : entityManager.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Student s");
        studentList = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? java.util.Collections.emptyList() : studentQuery.getResultList();
        studentQuery1 = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : entityManager.createQuery("SELECT s FROM Student s");
        studentList1 = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? java.util.Collections.emptyList() : studentQuery1.getResultList();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTable1 = new javax.swing.JTable();
        jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 204, 204));

        jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null},
                {null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Enroll NO.", "Name", "Present"
            }
        ) {
            Class[] types = new Class [] {
                java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Object.class, java.lang.Boolean.class
            };

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types [columnIndex];
            }
        });
        jTable1.setGridColor(new java.awt.Color(0, 204, 204));
        jTable1.setName("Attendance "); // NOI18N
        jTable1.setRowSelectionAllowed(false);
        jTable1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jTable1MouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jTable1.addPropertyChangeListener(new java.beans.PropertyChangeListener() {
            public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                jTable1PropertyChange(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTable1);

        jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8" }));
        jComboBox1.setSelectedItem(null);
        jComboBox1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jComboBox1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setText("Sem");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 533, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(15, 15, 15))
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(173, 173, 173)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(35, 35, 35)
                .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 244, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        Vatt1 p = new Vatt1();
        String sem = (String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
        Vector rows = p.getRecords(sem);
        Vector columns = p.getColumns();
        DefaultTableModel dm = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
        dm.setDataVector(rows, columns);
    }                                          

    private void jTable1PropertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:

    }                                      

    private void jTable1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                    

    public Vector getColumns() {
        Vector columns = new Vector();
        columns.add("Roll No");
        columns.add("Name");
        columns.add("Present");
       return columns;
    }

    public Vector getRecords(String sem) {
        Vector rows = new Vector();
        try {
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();

            String sql = "SELECT  std_id,std_name FROM student where  sem=" + sem;
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            while (rs.next()) {
                Vector temp = new Vector();
                temp.addElement(rs.getString(1));
                temp.addElement(rs.getString(2));
                temp.addElement(Boolean.FALSE);
                rows.addElement(temp);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            System.out.println("Here One");
            return null;
        }
        return rows;
    }


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Vatt1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Vatt1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Vatt1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Vatt1.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Vatt1().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.persistence.EntityManager entityManager;
    private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    private java.util.List<my.stdams.Student> studentList;
    private java.util.List<my.stdams.Student> studentList1;
    private javax.persistence.Query studentQuery;
    private javax.persistence.Query studentQuery1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: You mentioned some code - none is posted! Can you please refer the tutorial that you followed?

Comment: You should paste the code.

Comment: @lolsvemir this is code please help me i edited what is want to do .i have to  complete my project till 13

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) with more DDL and less `null`s.